# swap between char arrays

Tags: arrays, char, swap

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between running the above code on 8 byte (64-bit) platform and 4 byte (32-bit) platform: running it on 4 byte platform doesn't work – arrays are not swapped; on 8 byte it works, but with warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void switchNames(char **a, char **b)
{
    char* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main ()
{
    char labc[10] = "labc";
    char labcpp[10] = "labcpp";
    printf("Before switch: labc = %s, labcpp = %s\n", labc,    labcpp);
    switchNames(&labc, &labcpp);
    printf("After switch: labc = %s, labcpp = %s\n", labc,    labcpp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the warnings?  They will tell you the cause of the problem.  The behavior of your code is undefined.  `&labc` and `&labcpp` have type `char * const *`, (const pointer to pointer to char), but you are passing them to a function expecting `char **` (pointer to pointer to char).  I'm surprised it works under any circumstances.  This code should compile without warnings and work as expected:

```
char *labc = "labc";
char *labcpp = "labcpp";
char **a = &labc;
char **b = &labcpp;

switchNames(a, b);
```

Do not ignore compiler warnings.  And get a copy of *C: A Reference Manual* by Harbison and Steele.

Answer (score 1):

Hello. You should allocate 2 new target strings (char *) for that on the heap (using new) within method, then do a stringcopy, delete, etc. Maybe does make sense to use exception handling in case you reside in programming with const char * in your main(). Stringizing operator might be helpful when working on the heap .. :-)

```
// Preprocessor string constants
#define TEXT1 Hello 12345
```